# Display sharepoint list items in form

Tags: list, list-form

I am looking for a way to use sharepoint to automatically fill inn information from a  sharepoint list into various forms. Typically network useragreements for different networks, employment contracts etc.

When new employees arrive we have to fill in 10 different forms using the same information, such as last name, first name, DOB, employee number, phone number etc.

I am looking for a way to put all that information in a list in sharepoint and be able auto generate forms with all the fields automatically filled out in the form using the data in the sharepoint list.

I've tried to use infopath and i created a data connection to the sharepoint list. I am able to display fields individually using sharepoint list data and drop down buttons, but im not able to link them up to change value when the value of other fields are changed. When i select "John Johnson" in the first field, i want the rest of the fields to be populated with data from the same line in the sharepoint list as John Johnson.

Intention is to be able to print off forms ready for signatures without handjamming everything. I dont want to manipulate sharepoint list data in the form so i need a read only solution.

Any advice on the matter i greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have got the data source to display and the issue is managing the change of name as per this question. It is simple. You need to create an action which will trigger when the name is selected. 
[image]

Assume the combo box here as your name selector. In the Manage Rules section I have set the field2's value to be "A" when field1's value change. Likewise you can set the data from your data source to filter by the value of the combo box.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! For some reason im not able to make the formula work. My other boxes are coming up with true or false. Is the '"A"' in the formula a reference to a column name in the sharepoint list?